# RegExp multiply matches in text

Tags: c#, regex

I want to write a regexp to get multiple matches of the first character and next three digits. Some valid examples:
A123,
V322,
R333.
I try something like that

```
[a-aA-Z](1)\d3
```

but it gets me just the first match!
[image]
Could you possibly show me, how to rewrite this regexp to get multiple results?Thank you so much and Have a nice day!

Comment: Your char class `[a-aA-Z]` will only match lowercase `a` and uppercase `A-Z`. I'm not sure if that's what you're going for.

Comment: What do you mean _first character_ ? What is first about it?

Comment: `[[:alpha:]]\d{3}` [Test](https://regex101.com/r/K6rgA6/1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex does not work because it matches:

- `[a-aA-Z]` - an ASCII letter, then
- `(1)`  - a `1` digit (and puts into a capture)
- `\d` - any 1 digit
- `3`  -  a `3` digit.

So, it matches `Y193`, `E103`, etc., even in longer phrases, where `Y` and `E` are not *first* letters.

You need to use a word boundary and fix your pattern as

```
\b[a-aA-Z][0-9]{3}
```

NOTE: if you need to match it as a whole word, add `\b` at the end: `\b[a-aA-Z][0-9]{3}\b`.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%5ba-aA-Z%5d%5b0-9%5d%7b3%7d&i=Some+text%2c+Z123+text%2c+B456+here.).

**Details**:

- `\b`  - leading word boundary
- `[a-aA-Z]` - an ASCII letter
- `[0-9]{3}` - 3 digits.

C# code:

```
var results = Regex.Matches(s, @"\b[a-aA-Z][0-9]{3}")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(m => m.Value)
        .ToList();
```

Comment: I doubt it going to help as the q us likely about match vs matches.

Comment: The problem is only that OP does not understand how to test a regex at regex101.com. However, there  is little sense testing a .NET regex in an online Web tester that does not support .NET regex syntax. Anyway, I also suggest the code that should help.

Comment: Great answer @WiktorStribiżew Thank you so much!

Comment: Always glad to help.